# How to increase the push/pull frequency of SymmetricDS

Tags: symmetricds

We would like the updates in our stores tables to be pushed instantly to the corp table, or as fast as possible. Currently it takes 10 - 25 seconds.

Can we increase the push/pull job frequencies in SymmetricDS

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the referenced properties.  They can be adjusted in the engine properties file or in sym_parameter:

```
job.push.period.time.ms (default 60 secs)
job.pull.period.time.ms (default 60 secs)
job.routing.period.time.ms (default 10 secs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. You'll have to increase the frequency of the router job before doing the same for the push and/or pull job(s):

http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.9/html/user-guide.html#_jobs_2

To have data to push or pull it has to be routed and ready for syncing. Change the values of job frequencies in the symmetric-ds.properties file which will take presedence over default properties.